# How do you specify nodes on `mpirun`'s command line?

Tags: linux, mpi

How do I use `mpirun`'s `-machine` flag?

To select which cluster node to execute on, I figured out to use `mpirun`'s `-machinefile` option like this

```
> mpirun -machinefile $HOME/utils/Host_file -np <integer> <executable-filename>
```

`Host_file` contains a list of the nodes, one on each line.

But I want to submit a whole bunch of processes with different arguments and I don't want them running on the same node. That is, I want to do something like

```
> mpirun -machinefile $HOME/utils/Host_file -np 1 filename 1
nano Host_file % change the first node name
> mpirun -machinefile $HOME/utils/Host_file -np 1 filename 2
nano Host_file
> mpirun -machinefile $HOME/utils/Host_file -np 1 filename 3
nano Host_file
...
```

I could use the `-machine` flag and then just type a different node for each execution. But I can't get it to work.  For example

```
> mpirun -machine node21-ib -np 1 FPU
> mpirun -machine node21 -np 1 FPU
```

always executes on the master node.

I also tried the `-nodes` option

```
> mpirun -nodes node21-ib -np 1 FPU
> mpirun -nodes node21 -np 1 FPU
```

But that just executes on my current node.

Similarly, I've tried the `-nolocal` and `-exclude` options without success.

So I have a simple question: *How do I use the `-machine` option? Or is there a better way to do this (for a Linux newbie)?*

I'm using the following version of MPI, which seems to have surprisingly little documentation on the web (so far, the entirety of the documentation I have comes from `> mpirun --help`).

```
> mpichversion
MPICH Version:          1.2.7
MPICH Release date:     $Date: 2005/06/22 16:33:49$
MPICH Patches applied:  none
MPICH configure:        --with-device=ch_gen2 --with-arch=LINUX -prefix=/usr/local/mvapich-gcc --with-romio --without-mpe -lib=-L/usr/lib64 -Wl,-rpath=/usr/lib64 -libverbs -libumad -lpthread
MPICH Device:           ch_gen2
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Doesn't your cluster run under the control of a resource manager like SGE, LSF, Torque, etc? These usually provide ways to integrate with the MPI implementation to automatically provide the correct nodefile for each job.

Comment: I have no idea what SGE, LSF, or Torque are. I doubt we have any of those things. The cluster is a bare bones cluster which is owned and administered by a math professor who is not a computer expert.

Comment: The owner tells me that `torque` is installed, but not active. He has no plans to make it active.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to specific a hosts file

for example at your `mpirun` command  try  `mpirun -np 4 -hostfile hosts ./exec`

where hosts contains your ip address generally `192.168.1.201:8` where the last digit is the maximum number of cores, separate each node by a newline. Ideally you should install some cluster management software like torque and maui for example.

Comment: pyC, I'm afraid I don't understand your answer at all (not even enough to ask a good question about it). I already have -machinefile working, which has a list of nodes, which sounds similar to what you suggest. Also, `mpirun --help` does not show any `-hostfile` option (and there is no `man mpirun` entry. I tried `mpirun -np 4 -hostfile  $HOME/utils/Host_file ./exec`, but it ran exactly the same way that `mpirun -np 4 -machinefile $HOME/utils/Host_file ./exec` ran. Can you add some more detail please?